# Replace/Remove EventListener from Buttons

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to remove an event listener from some buttons and it seems that my code was not doing anything. I have a map that has icons for places that have restaurants. Each icon has an event listener that triggers a function `showInfo`:

```
let showInfo = function(target, locationInfo) {
    // handler
    let toggleBtn = function(event) {
        if (event.target.id === 'covidClosedBtn') {
            openBtn.classList.remove('active');
            closedBtn.classList.add('active');
        } else if (event.target.id === 'covidOpenBtn') {
            closedBtn.classList.remove('active');
            openBtn.classList.add('active');
        }
    }

    // add event listener to the closedBtn
    if (closedBtn.getAttribute('listener') !== 'true') {
        closedBtn.setAttribute('listener', 'true');
        closedBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleBtn, false);
    } else if (closedBtn.getAttribute('listener') === 'true') {
        console.log('I want to remove this listener');
        // this removeEventListener line does nothing
        closedBtn.removeEventListener('click', toggleBtn, false);
    }
```

When `showInfo` is called I add event listeners to both the open and closed button but to keep it simple I am focusing on the closed button to illustrate my difficulty.

The first time I click on an icon these buttons will have an attribute of `listener` added to indicate a listener exists. Any subsequent clicks should replace/remove the event listener and add a new one. The reason I need to do this is because I want the `locationInfo` for the icon to be available each time a different icon is clicked so I can further manipulate that information within the `showInfo` closure.

However, in my case the listener doesn't get removed. I have attempted to create a clone of the button and replace the old button with `cloneNode` but this causes the `closedBtn` variable to lose reference and I can no longer attach any listeners to it or manipulate its classes later on in my method.

I believe my handler in the remove method is not strictly equal to what it was when it was added but I cannot think of a solution for my scenario. How can I successfully remove/replace this event listener?

Comment: Do you even get this message: 
I want to remove this listener ?

Comment: Hello. Yes I do get that message but as Yoric mentioned the remove listener won't do anything and it will silently fail since the two ```toggleBtn``` closures are now distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that  you're calling `showInfo` twice, once to add and once to remove the listener?

If that's the case, then yes, the two closures `toggleBtn` are distinct. If you wish to make sure that you only have one `toggleBtn`, you must keep it outside of `showInfo`.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. ```showInfo``` will be called any time an icon is clicked by the user on the map. Thank you for confirming that the instances are distinct and it makes a whole lot more sense now. It seems my approach has forced me into a design that isn't exactly ideal.